# Iframe with pointer-events:none hijacks clicks in Safari on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, iframe

When there is an iframe overlaying page contents with pointer-events none, any click goes through it and is registred by elements underneath the iframe. But for some reason this is not true in Safari on iOS. I have built a simple [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwftnb4q/4/) if you're on PC you can click the green text and it will show "Hello World", but on iPhone the iframe hijacks the click and nothing happens. Is this intended? If not can I report it somewhere?

The code is:
**HTML**

```
<p onclick="$('#hidden').show()">
Clicking me shows Hello World underneath. But in Safari on iOS the iframe ovalaying me hijacks the clicks even though it has pointer events none
</p>
<p id="hidden" style="display:none">
Hello World!
</p>
<iframe id="iframe" src=""></iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
#iframe {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: orange;
opacity: 0.2;
pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this or workaround?

Comment: This is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a negative z-index, like `z-index: -1000;` for example, to your `#iframe` solves this issue. I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwftnb4q/6/), which does work now on iOS.